# How to resolve "!! template: conf: 2: unexpected unclosed action in command"

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to launch a container with Docker and nginx.
However, I do not understand the reason for "!! template: conf: 2: unexpected unclosed action in command".
I want you to tell me if you understand.
I am currently working on Docker and nginx with reference to books

The content of the error changed when the description of upstream.conf.tmpl was deleted
I think upstream.conf.tmpl is the cause

**compose**

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    image: api_production_nginx
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.17.9

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget https://github.com/progrium/entrykit/releases/download/v0.4.0/entrykit_0.4.0_linux_x86_64.tgz
RUN tar -xvzf entrykit_0.4.0_linux_x86_64.tgz
RUN rm entrykit_0.4.0_linux_x86_64.tgz
RUN mv entrykit /usr/local/bin/
RUN entrykit --symlink

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
COPY ./compose/production/nginx/nginx.conf.tmpl /etc/nginx/
COPY ./compose/production/nginx/conf.d/* /etc/nginx/conf.d/

ENTRYPOINT [ \
  "render", \
      "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", \
      "--", \
  "render", \
      "/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf", \
      "--", \
  "render", \
      "/etc/nginx/conf.d/public.conf", \
      "--" \
]

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

upstream.conf.tmpl

```
upstream backend {
    server {{ var "BACKEND_HOST" }} max_fails={{ var "BACKEND_MAX_FAILS" |
    default "3"}} fail_timeout={{ var "BACKEND_FAIL_TIMEOUT" | default "90s" }}
}
```

**Append.**
The error changed by adding a line break.

```
upstream backend {
    server {{ var "BACKEND_HOST" }}
    max_fails={{ var "BACKEND_MAX_FAILS" | default "3" }}
    fail_timeout={{ var "BACKEND_FAIL_TIMEOUT" | default "90s" }}
}
```

```
 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf:5
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf:5
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  For example, identify which specific configuration file is having the issue, and remove the others from the question?  What have you already tried to isolate or resolve the problem?

Comment: Reduced as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the last semicolon of "fail_timeout = {{var" BACKEND_FAIL_TIMEOUT "| default" 90s "}};" fixed it.